# how to get sum of two columns based on the vale in third column and group by a fourth column?

Tags: php, mysql, database, group-by

I have a MySQL table where table has four columns state,Dr_amount,Cr_amount,Type, I want to know the sum of each state's Dr_amount and Cr_amount with two different conditions where type=in and where type=out

I have tried with the below code but is calculating each entry of columns

```
select *,(select sum(Credit_Rs) from expense where type = 'Received') as crsum,(select sum(Debit_Rs) from expense where type = 'Expense') as drsum from expense group by state order by state
```

Below is the table with sample Entries

```
Month   Debit (Rs) Credit (Rs) Type
Bihar               150000     IN    
Bihar   50000        50000     OUT   
Bihar   15000        10000     OUT   
UP      0           100000     IN
```

I want the result like this

```
Month   Debit (Rs) Credit (Rs) 
Bihar   65000      150000        
UP      0          100000
```

Comment: what you get with your query? what is wrong?

Comment: Month   Debit (Rs) Credit (Rs) 
Bihar     65000      250000        
UP        65000      250000

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `case when expression`

```
select state,sum(Debit_Rs),sum(case when Type='IN' then Credit_Rs end)
from tablename
group by state
order by state
```